# Drag component to create another one

Tags: java, swing, ide, drag-and-drop

In all major Java IDEs, there is a GUI designer.
When we select a component (A `Jbutton`, for example) and move it to a `JPanel` or `JFrame`, how is it done?
Is it a copy of the dragged component that is created on the other container?

On a project I'm working on, I have some `JButton` I would like to be able to drag to a panel. Theses `JButton` represent some actions, like "copy file", "move file", etc...
When one of those `JButton` is dragged, some options of the action will be displayed.

I checked [`TransferHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html) but I don't know if it's the way to go. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible. You'll need to study the [*Drag and Drop*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) tutorial. In particular, you may want to implement [*Drop Location Rendering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/droplocation.html), discussed [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1350570), to symbolize the action.

By encapsulating a button's name, icon, listener, etc. in an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instance, your `importData()` implementation can easily use `setAction()` to change the target button's behavior dynamically.

An alternative approach might be to add your buttons to a [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html). In normal mode, clicking the button *evokes* the `Action`; in editor mode , clicking the button *changes* the `Action`, again via `setAction()`, to one chosen from a list.