# Show component that is being dragged java

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have drag and drop working for my jlabels, but I want to show the actual labels being dragged. So I when they are dragged, I don't want the normal hand with a square under it. So it should disappear from its starting position, and follow the mouse. I tried setting the location but it's not working, the mouse still shows the usual icons. I can make it disappear from its starting location but not completely move.

Would it work if I used a layered pane to make another pane on top and set the locations of the labels there?

```
private class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            JComponent c = (JComponent)e.getSource();
            TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
            c.setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x);
            //c.setOpaque(true);
            handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);

        }


    }
```

Comment: See also *Drop Location Rendering*, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13315105/230513).

Comment: I would spend some time having a look Timothy Wall's [The Rabbit Hole](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/) blog, in particular [this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/04/smooth-jlist-drop-target-animation.html) and [this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/05/smooth-tree-drop-animation.html) and [this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/05/my-drag-image-is-better-than-yours.html) and [this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/06/dead-simple-drags.html) and [this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/06/fancy-drops.html) and [this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/07/drag-images-for-everyoneand-we-do-mean.html)

Comment: ...and [this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/08/drop-target-navigation-or-you-drag.html) and [possibly this](//rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2006/08/swing-drag-images-improved.html)